# Wpf. Прозрачность елементов

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В общем суть очень проста. Код формы:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="Green" Opacity="0.5" Margin="116,74,263,171"/>
    <Border Background="Green" Opacity="0.5" Margin="202,74,159,171"/>
</Grid>
```

Если эти 2 border пересекутся[image: введите сюда описание изображения] то в местах пересечения Opacity будет не 0.5 а 1. Мне надо что бы Opacity не менялась в местах пересечения.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужны гриды? Посмотрите в сторону геометрии: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level13/13_3.php

Comment: Мне просто надо что бы прозрачность не менялась. Геометрия не подходит

Comment: ОК, это невозможно, потому что это правильное поведение — прозрачность каждого отдельного грида остается так же 0,5 и сквозь верхний грид просвечивается нижний, который тоже имеет некоторый цвет фона. Опишите свою реальную задачу и мы подумаем как ее решить по другому. Может быть с помощью геометрии или чего-то еще.

Comment: Я хочу сделать ripple ефект на кнопке. Шел по этой статти: https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/wpf-ripple-effect . Все прекрасно работает, но если нажимать много раз, то круг начинает рисоваться заново. Я решил это путем динамического добавления круга в кнопку, и его прорисовку. Так вот, если много раз нажимать, начинает прорисовываться много кругов, а opacity каждого круга 0.5. Соответственно они стакаются, чего мне не нужно. Вот например в телеграме такого не происходит. Можешь проверить, понажимать на кнопочки.